# JMeter: Send gzipped json?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have a web service I need to test with JMeter but the spec requires compressed json.  I need to create the json from data in a CSV file.  I have been able to work that out using a beanshell preprocessor and a CSV dataset config. But now I need a way to gzip the data and send it to the server.  Is there some sampler out there that will do this?

**Hackish Solution**

The only working solution I've found is to compress the data from the beanshell script then have JMeter send the file, but this seems a bit nasty to me.

```
import com.eclipsesource.json.*;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

jsonObject = new JsonObject();
// populate json data here

GZIPOutputStream zip = new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("c:\\json.gz"));
writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(zip, "UTF-8"));
jsonObject.writeTo(writer);
writer.close();
```

If there are no samplers that do the compression, is there a way to avoid writing the data to the file system? Should I make a post processor to delete the temp file?  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

None of the samplers I know will automatically zip for you.

You can use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of `FileOutputStream`, then `toString` it to a jmeter variable or property, so you can use it in the sampler using the variable name.

```
import com.eclipsesource.json.*;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

jsonObject = new JsonObject();
// populate json data here

GZIPOutputStream zip = new GZIPOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(zip, "UTF-8"));
jsonObject.writeTo(writer);
writer.close();

vars.put("ZIPFILE", zip.toString());
```

Then in the `Body Data` section of your http request, refer to the variable `${ZIPFILE}`

Comment: it just send `${ZIPFILE}` for me